# Is it possible to declare user-defined statements in python (same syntax of assert)?

Tags: python, overriding, statements, user-defined

For example, what assert does:

`assert <boolean assertion to check>, <error string/value outputted if that assertion False>`

What I would like to do:

`mycommand <boolean assertion to check>, <value that will get returned if assertion is False>`

It would be the same as doing:

```
if not <boolean assertion to check>: return <value>
```

but concisely, with a simple one-liner. I know I should just use this last one, but I am more interested on finding out how much you can override/customize python.

Comment: You can't. The closest you can get is a function (although obviously you can't handling returning from a separate function). You could write your own preprocessor or try finding an existing one, but there's no built-in way.

Comment: Might be worth reading through this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669921/adding-macros-to-python

Comment: If you write code that needs so many of these kinds of statements that you're thinking about customising Python like this, then I'd suggest you should rather write the code differently, as that sounds like a red flag. 

Comment: Or write in a lisp where this kind of thinking is common and even encouraged (I recommend Clojure).

Comment: @deceze I knew I was going to get this answer and you are probably right lol.. anyway, what if I have to perform multiple checks on a Flask GET instance for some json content? [current snippet] (https://i.imgur.com/u8FbMSu.png)

Comment: I'd probably dress that up as many individual validation functions/classes which each raise their own sort of `ValidationException` and chain them. More a declarative approach than a procedural one. E.g., libraries like WTForms and such implement this kind of approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use any "user-defined" syntax, but you could just use `assert` itself and use a decorator to make the function return the value instead of raising an `AssertionError`:

```
def assert_to_return(f):
    def _f(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except AssertionError as e:
            return e.args[0] if e.args else None
    return _f

@assert_to_return
def div(x, y):
    assert y != 0, float("nan")
    return x / y

print(div(42, 5)) # 8.4
print(div(42, 0)) # nan
```

This way, the `assert <condition>, <value>` line means "check whether `<condition>` holds, otherwise immediately return `<value>`", i.e. pretty much exactly what you wanted. If the `<value>` is omitted, the function will just return `None` in that case, as defined in the decorator. Also note that `<value>` is only evaluated if the `assert` is violated, i.e. it could also contain an expensive function call or side-effects that you do not want to occur otherwise.

Of course, while other exceptions will work just fine, any `AssertionError` raised by `assert` statements in functions your function is calling will *also* bei caught and handled by the decorator. If this is a problem, you could either (a) wrap the `<value>` in some special wrapper object and only return those in `_f`, otherwise re-raise the `AssertionError`, or (b) wrap all the functions you call in your function that might also raise an `AssertionError` so that their `AssertionErrors` are wrapped in another exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think this is the closest to what I was looking for. It's interesting to see a solution that involves decorators, I didn't know much about them.

Answer (score 2):

If what you are looking for a one-expression `if` statement (rather than an assertion that causes failure if false), then do this:

`<value> if <boolean assertion to check> else <another value>`

If you don't have anything for  `<another value>`, it is Pythonic to let that be `None`.

`x = 3 if 10<5 else None` gives `x` the value `None`.

`x = 3 if 10>5 else None` gives `x` the value `3`.